# Display JSX file in Chrome instead of downloading it

Tags: google-chrome, reactjs

When I click a .JSX file in Chrome it downloads it. How can I display the .JSX file in the browser like a regular .JS file.

**Example**

If I browse http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/ from Chrome and view the page source, there are a few .JSX script files loaded by this page. However, if I click any of those links, the .JSX file is downloaded rather than displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the proper content headers. `application/javascript`

Check out [Facebook's docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html) how to compile jsx on the fly in the browser.

Comment: It is not a file I serve so I have no control over the content header. I was looking more for a browser configuration solution.

Comment: Can we see the markup or configuration that you currently have in place?

Comment: There is a no markup to share. When I view the source of a website that references a .JSX script file and I try to view that file in Chrome, Chrome will download the file rather than display the text of the file in the browser. It is as simple as that. I'm just trying to see if there are Chrome settings that can be set to NOT download a file with a .JSX extension and DISPLAY it instead.